# remove coupon code from cart

Tags: magento2, programmatically, coupon-codes, remove

I want to delete the coupon code programmatically. My code is:

```
$cart = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

  if(isset($response_json['errorMessage']) || $json_response['status']['statusCode'] == 0){
    $cart->setCouponCode('');
    $cart->collectTotals()->save();
    $this->logger->debug("test");
  }
```

I see the "test" in my debug. But the Coupon code not removed. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: From where you are getting $cartId? And where does you added this code?

Comment: I added this code in my plugin and the beforePlaceOrder function. But the answer of Jaimin Sutariya works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below.

```
if(isset($response_json['errorMessage']) || $json_response['status']['statusCode'] == 0){
    $cart->setCouponCode('');
    $this->quoteRepository->save($cart->collectTotals());
    $this->logger->debug("test");
}
```

Comment: yes, it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest another way. Go to your xml file and put this code at before body tag close

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```